# Cleaner way to hook into the window.onload of a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, wkwebview

I'm building a small iOS App in Swift and I use the [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/). What I am trying to achieve is to be notified when a web page has rendered completely. It is a known issue with [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/) that none of its loading notifications work.

However, this approach seems to work and the idea is to hook into the `window.onload` function in Javascript and notify Swift from there. However, here too I found an issue. If I use JQuery, in some pages the callback doesn't happen apparently because the web pages already define `window.onload`. If I use the pure Javascript way, some web pages break i.e. they don't load at all apparently because I'm overriding the `window.onload`.

```
// using JQuery, this function never get called for web pages that do window.onload = 
$(window).load(function() { 
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage(
        JSON.stringify({body: "window finished loading"}));
});
// works always but breaks web pages that use window.onload
window.onload = function() {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage(
        JSON.stringify({body: "window finished loading"}));
};
```

The question is how can I append this line notification to an existing `window.onload` and define one `window.onload` if it doesn't exist? other ideas also welcome e.g. queuing `window.load` implementations?

For completeness I have included below the two known ways to get such notifications using `WKWebView` natively.

**(1) getting `WKNavigationDelegate` life-cycle notifications** but the callback notification triggers too early when the web page has not yet rendered completely.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // ...
    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        NSLog("didFinishNavigation callback received ... too early!")
    }
}
```

**(2) Using the Key-Value Observer method (KVO)** but here again callback notification triggers too early too:

```
webView.addObserver(viewController, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress", options: .New, context: nil)
//
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<()>) {
    guard let webView = object as? WKWebView else {return}
    guard let change = change else {return}
    guard let keyPath = keyPath else {return}
    switch keyPath {
        case "estimatedProgress":
            if ((1.0 - webView.estimatedProgress) < 1e-10) {
                NSLog("'estimatedProgress' callback received ... too early!")
            }
            break
        default: break
    }
}
```

it is the same issue for the "loading" KVO.

**UPDATE:** in addition to the accepted answer, the top ranked answer to this other question [running-jquery-after-all-other-js-has-executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494773/running-jquery-after-all-other-js-has-executed) solves this OP too by polling the DOM for a specific change e.g. when all the Javascript has completed in addition to the loading of the page.

Comment: [`$(document).ready(fn)`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) or the shorthand `$(fn);` The function you pass `fn` is called later when the page is ready. If you add another ready handler after the page is ready, jquery will call your ready callback immediately.

Comment: Unfortunately it has the same issue as when using `$(window).load(fn)`.

Comment: Thank you! I meant, using $(document).ready(fn) has the same issue as using $(window).load(fn) I tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way that works. However despite my futile attempt to avoid duplicate notifications I still get two notifications for some web pages and haven't found a way to fix it yet ...

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load",
        function() {
            // try to make sure it is called only once ...
            if (typeof window.isMyiOSAppAlreadyNotified === 'undefined') {
                // notify my iOS App that the page has finished loading 
                window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage(
                    JSON.stringify({body: "window onload"}));
            }
            window.isMyiOSAppAlreadyNotified = true;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: If you want something like jquery document ready, you want `DOMContentLoaded` like the other answer says. The `load` event happens much later, after everything is completely loaded. It is almost always unnecessary to wait until whole load.

Comment: Can you provide a complete solution, showing how the above is wrapped in Objective-C or Swift, and how it is invoked?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event you can listen to [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

Also you can perform the callback at the end of the execution stack by doing the following:

```
window.setTimeout(callback, 0);
```

Additionally you can try calling `removeEventListener` in your callback.

**For Example:**

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    var documentIsReady = function() {
        window.removeEventListener("load", documentIsReady);

        if (typeof window.isMyiOSAppAlreadyNotified === 'undefined') {
            window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage(JSON.stringify({body: "window onload"}));
        }
        window.isMyiOSAppAlreadyNotified = true;
    };
    window.addEventListener("load", function() { window.setTimeout(documentIsReady, 0); });
}
```

To avoid polluting the global(window) scope with variables like `isMyiOSAppAlreadyNotified` you can apply the [module pattern](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually I am interested in the latest possible time to be notified i.e. "perform the callback at the end of the execution stack" this would be perfect .. could you provide a complete and self contained answer? and I will accept ,,,

Comment: Can you provide a complete solution, showing how the above is wrapped in Objective-C or Swift, and how it is invoked?